# How to pass object (or array) to PHP from jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have an array that I'm trying to pass to a php file which is passing, but it shows the array as a string. How do I convert the string to an array so I can go through it in php? Here's my code:

**jQuery**

```
$('#add-child').click(function()
{
    var _attributes = [];
    $('#attributes input').each(function()
    {
        _attributes.push($(this).val());
    });
    $.post('../assets/hub.php',{'task':'add-child','parent':$('#parent-id').val(),'value':$('#child-value').val(),'attributes':JSON.stringify(_attributes)},function(callback)
    {
        console.log(callback);
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
case 'add-child':
    $department = $_POST['parent'];
    $category   = $_POST['value'];        
    $attributes = $_POST['attributes'];
    print($department.' : '.$category.' : '.$attributes);
break;
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
test1 : test2 : ["sdfg","34","vsdf"]
```

** EDIT **

I removed `JSON.stringify()` and added `var_dump()` and this is the output:

```
string(3) "114"
string(4) "asdf"
array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "asdf"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "ZVCX"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "asdfr"
```

}

Comment: Why don't you pass `_attributes` value as-is? **WHY** do you apply `JSON.stringify` for it?

Comment: I tried that and I get an error > Array to string conversion in ...

Comment: because you're concatenating variables assuming they are string at line `print($department.' : '.$category.' : '.$attributes);`. While `$attributes` is an array.

Comment: You converted the data to JSON. Now you have to parse it into a PHP array.

Comment: @Felix Kling: .. or remove conversion (since it pointless) ))

Comment: "and this is the output:" --- so? It's the expected, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `JSON.stringify` at all and you check that everything is passed successfully using

```
var_dump($department, $category, $attributes);
```

not the `pring_r` with concatenations

Comment: hey zerkms, I did what you said and put the `var_dump()` results up in my post.

Comment: @Mike: and you get expected result. Everything works, doesn't it?

Comment: Well, I learned I'm an idiot .. really? I'm gonna concatenate a string and array and expected it to work? Rookie mistake. Also YES! It does output my result when I do the following `print($attributes[0]);` Thanks, and good job ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$attributes = json_decode($_POST['attributes']);
```

if you want to join the array back agian with a comma then

```
$attributes = implode(',' , json_decode($_POST['attributes']));
```

Comment: Hey Atif, I tried what you suggested and I get > Array to string conversion in ...

Comment: @Mike hey Mike, Im sorry I didn't understand what you said can you explain it clearly

Comment: @Atif Mohammed Ameenuddin: he says that he concatenates variables (strings and array) and wonders why array cannot be converted to a string :)))

Comment: @zerkms but the questions says "How do I convert the string to an array do I can go through it in php?"